# The div won't hide Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(500);
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = 'Plaats een Feed &#187;';
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show(500);
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = 'Afbreken (x)';
    document.getElementById('show').id = 'hide';
  });
});
</script>
```

**The div won't hide with the code above**

I am trying to make a script what will show and hide a div by clicking on a button. The text in the button has to change, and this works. If you click on the button, it will hide the div. But it's not happening. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Because you are hiding "p" i.e. paragraph. The first paragraph in your markup will be hidden.

Comment: If the div is `<div id="hide">` then your code should be `$(this).hide(500)`

Comment: @RahulPatil actually *all* the `<p>` blocks in the document will be hidden, not just the first one.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, then use jQuery. Use `$('#show').html('Afbreken (x)')` instead of `document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = 'Afbreken (x)';`

Comment: @Pointy Yes, my bad didn't know that. sorry..

Comment: Check this one: http://jsbin.com/vifuy/1/ is that what are you looking for @user3661693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vifuy/1/edit)**

As you mentioned that the IDs of the button will be changing dynamically, the below code will suit your need. Check the demo and confirm if that's what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', "#hide", function(){
    $("#divId").hide(500);  // considering you have div with id divID
    $(this).text( 'Plaats een Feed &#187;');
    this.id = 'show';
  });
  $(document).on('click',"#show", function(){
    $("#divId").show(500);  // considering you have div with id divID
    $(this).text('Afbreken (x)');
    this.id = 'hide';
  });
});
```

**HTML** i assumed based on the question:

```
<div id="divId">
   Some content in p tag
</div>


<button id="hide" value="hide">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 element that you want to show/hide, you can't use ids. You get the reference of the element that has been clicked through 'this' with the event.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hide").click(function(){
    $(this).hide(500);
    $(this).text('Plaats een Feed &#187;');
  });
  $(".show").click(function(){
    $(this).show(500);
    $(this).text('Afbreken (x)');
    $(this).removeClass('show');
    $(this).addClass('hide');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think I explained it wrong. The thing I want is the following:

- The first time you click, a div has to open and the text has to change to cancel.
- The second time you click, the div has to close and the text has to change back to post a message.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `style` `visibility` `hidden` or `none` and the `height` and `width` to `0` also if desired.

Comment: If we set visibility hidden, then still the div will take the space. instead display: none is a good option. But it doesn't answer the OP's question

Comment: Set height and width to 0 also then.